# What are some best practices to clean up http mix content warnings?

Tags: errors, ssl, https

I have a WordPress site with SSL Certificate.

Some of my web pages (i.e. `https://www.example.com/contact`) don't display the green SSL Lock in the address bar but display `https://`

I noticed a bunch of errors due to image files, like in the screenshot below that appear on those pages. What is an easy and fast way to convert all `http` requests to `https`?

[image: Mixed Content Warning Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [css-tricks.com](https://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/console-warnings.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot, it looks like you are displaying images from another website (`nga.gov`), for example:

```
http://images.nga.gov/?service=asset&action=show_preview&asset=120079
```

After checking out the links with the mixed content warning, I can see that SSL is set up for this website, which is good. However, their links still default to HTTP, for whatever reason.

To fix this on your end, simply change the protocol from `http://` to `https://`.

```
https://images.nga.gov/?service=asset&action=show_preview&asset=120079
```

You shouldn't get a warning once you manually update the links to the HTTPS protocols.

Additionally, you can consider using a plugin such as [Remove HTTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-http/) which strips the protocols from all of your URLs to help fix your mixed content warnings.

Comment: I'm using a child theme. Should I make this change in the parent theme too?

Comment: Make the changes where ever you added those links. If they were added in your parent theme as well, then yes.

Comment: Is the parent theme considered inactive because I am using a child theme? If so, why change those links if inactive?

Comment: No, because the child theme is dependent on the parent theme. However, the child theme writes over any additional change on top of the parent theme. So you could get away with just making the change on your child theme theoretically.